# N-body brute force python bodies disappearing to infinity

Tags: python, beginner

(I hope this isn't too general a question given I'm just pasting a bunch of code in, if that's the case then sorry)

*edited to remove the bit that wasn't working*

I've written a brute force implementation of the N-body simulation in Python with a leapfrog integration method (using numpy & numba's jit function to speed it up) but I'm not sure it's as well-written as it could be. Any comment on how I've done the various parts of this would be much appreciated, or any technique I'm missing to speed the code up or make it 'better'.

Bonus, please tell me if I've got any obvious rookie errors in my code!

The following code is my gravsim module which is then called by the second bit of code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

"""
units:
    G = 1
All other units can be defined as needed
"""
# G = 6.67430e-11
G = 1


@jit(nopython=True)
def force_point(location, m, masses, positions, eps, soft):
    """
    calculates gravitational force & GPE on an object at a location
    * both are softened by epsilon *
    Inputs:
        location: 1x3 array (location of point you want to measure, cartesian)
        m: float (mass of object)
        masses: Nx1 array
        positions: Nx3 array (cartesian)
        eps: float (softening constant) [assumes eps = 0]
        soft: bool (True = softening considered, False = not)
    Outputs:
        force: 1x3 array
        gpe: float
    """
    force = np.zeros((1, 3))
    gpe = 0.0
    for j in range(len(masses)):
        rj = positions[j, :]
        dr = rj - location  # vector distance between location & j
        dist_sq = (dr ** 2).sum()  # scalar distance between i & j squared
        softened_dist_sq = dist_sq + (eps ** 2)
        force_j = dr * (G * m * masses[j] / (softened_dist_sq ** (3 / 2)))
        force += force_j
        if soft:
            gpe -= G * m * masses[j] / np.sqrt(softened_dist_sq)
        else:
            gpe -= G * m * masses[j] / np.sqrt(dist_sq)
    return (force, gpe)


@jit(nopython=True)
def force_calculator(masses, positions, eps):
    """
    calculates: force due to gravity between N objects.
    Inputs:
        masses: Nx1 array
        positions: Nx3 array (cartesian)
        velocities: Nx3 array (only used for working out velocity
        of combined particles)
        combined: dict - set of combined particles
        eps: float (softening constant) [assumes eps = 0]
    Outputs:
        forces: Nx3 array (cartesian)
        gpe: Nx1 array
    """
    forces = np.zeros_like(positions)  # 3-vector
    gpe = np.zeros_like(masses)  # scalar

    for i in range(len(masses)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(masses)):
            ri = positions[i, :]
            rj = positions[j, :]
            dr = rj - ri  # vector distance between i & j
            dist_sq = np.sum(dr ** 2)  # scalar distance between i & j squared
            softened_dist = (dist_sq + (eps ** 2)) ** (3 / 2)
            force_ij = dr * (G * masses[i] * masses[j] / softened_dist)
            forces[i, :] += force_ij
            forces[j, :] += force_ij * -1
            gpe_ij = -1 * G * masses[i] * masses[j] / (np.sqrt(dist_sq) + eps)
            gpe[i] += gpe_ij
            gpe[j] += gpe_ij
    return (forces, gpe)


@jit(nopython=True)
def one_step(timestep, masses, mass3, positions, velocities, eps):
    """
    takes a set of masses, with positions & velocities, calc's force on them
    then finds positions & velocities at next timestep, using leapfrog
    integration method
    Inputs:
        timestep: float
        masses: Nx1 array
        mass3: Nx3 array (for matrix ops see below)
        positions: Nx3 array (cartesian)
        velocities: Nx3 array (cartesian)
        eps: float (softening constant) [assume eps = 0]
    currently, can't figure out how to add an ext field as an optional variable
    with numba (type is specified at runtime, so can't fuck with it)
    Outputs:
        r_update: Nx3 array of new positions (cartesian)
        v_update: Nx3 array of new velocities (cartesian)
        forces: Nx3 array of new forces (cartesian)
        kinetic: Nx1 array of KE's for position 2
        gpe: Nx1 array of GPE's for position 1
    mass3 is an Nx3 array of masses ie. {[m1 m1 m1] / [m2 m2 m2] / ...}
    this allows matrix ops to be used to update velocity & position which are
    quicker than looping
    """
    forces, gpe = force_calculator(masses, positions, eps)
    v_update = velocities + (forces * timestep / mass3)
    v_half = velocities + (forces * 0.5 * timestep / mass3)
    v_half_mag_sq = np.array([(v_half[i, :] ** 2).sum() for i in range(len(masses))])
    r_update = positions + v_update * timestep
    kinetic = 0.5 * masses * v_half_mag_sq
    return (r_update, v_update, forces, kinetic, gpe)


@jit(nopython=True)
def timeloop(nsteps, timestep, masses, positions, velocities, eps):
    """
    repeats the one-step process for n steps and records params at each step
    into Nx3x(nsteps) arrays
    Inputs:
        nsteps: int
        timestep: float
        masses: Nx1 array
        positions: Nx3 array (cartesian)
        velocities: Nx3 array (cartesian)
        eps: float (softening constant) [assume eps = 0]
    Outputs:
        r_times: Nx3x(nsteps) array (positions)
        v_times: Nx3x(nsteps) array (velocities)
        f_times: Nx3x(nsteps) array (forces)
        kinetic: Nx1x(nsteps) array
        gpe: Nx1x(nsteps) array
    """
    kinetic = np.empty((nsteps + 1, len(masses)))
    kinetic[0, :] = (
        0.5
        * masses
        * np.array([(velocities[i, :] ** 2).sum() for i in range(len(masses))])
    )
    gpe = np.empty((nsteps + 1, len(masses)))
    """
    in one_step, GPE is calc'ed for starting position but KE is calc'ed
    after the advance; so ke[0] must be calc'ed here. We will not have a final
    GPE until it's specifically calculated at the end.
    """
    r_times = np.zeros((nsteps + 1, len(masses), 3))
    v_times = np.zeros((nsteps + 1, len(masses), 3))
    f_times = np.zeros((nsteps + 1, len(masses), 3))

    r_times[0, :, :] += positions
    v_times[0, :, :] += velocities
    """
    this creates Nx3x(nsteps) arrays by making a list of arrays then using
    np.stack to form an array from the list, after setting the 1st array to
    the initial input values
    Reference r/v_times with [timestep, particle no, axis no]
    e.g. 1st timestep, 5th particle, y axis: [0,4,1]
    """
    mass3 = np.zeros((len(masses), 3))
    for i, mass in enumerate(masses):
        mass3[i, :] = [mass for p in range(3)]

    for n in range(nsteps):
        (
            r_times[n + 1, :, :],
            v_times[n + 1, :, :],
            f_times[n, :, :],
            kinetic[n + 1, :],
            gpe[n, :],
        ) = one_step(
            timestep, masses, mass3, r_times[n, :, :], v_times[n, :, :], eps,
        )
    f_times[-1, :, :], gpe[-1, :] = force_calculator(masses, r_times[-1, :, :], eps)
    # for final step, we don't need update x, v or ke, just force & gpe
    return (r_times, v_times, f_times, kinetic, gpe)
```

The second file is basically the simplest implementation, of 100 particles randomly in a 20x20x20 box with 0 initial velocity.

```py
import numpy as np
from gravsim import timeloop
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")
# initial conditions
steps = 1000
dt = 0.02
eps = 0.1
n = 100
m = np.ones(n)
radius = 10
rs = np.random.uniform(-radius, radius, size=(n, 3))
vs = np.zeros_like(rs)

# info
print("{} objects".format(n))
print("cube radius = {}".format(radius))
print("total time = {}".format(steps * dt))
print("softening = {}".format(eps))
# initial state scatter
f_in, a_in = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a_in.scatter(rs[:, 0], rs[:, 1], s=10)

# timeloop
xt, vt, ft, kt, gt = timeloop(steps, dt, m, rs, vs, eps)

k_sums = np.sum(kt, axis=1)
g_sums = np.sum(gt, axis=1)
e_total = k_sums + g_sums
virial = 2 * k_sums + g_sums

# system energy plot
f_e, a_e = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a_e.plot(k_sums, label="K")
a_e.plot(g_sums, label="U")
a_e.plot(e_total, label="K+U")
a_e.plot(virial, label="2K+U")
a_e.legend()
f_e.tight_layout()

# state at intervals scatter
f_xy, a_xy = plt.subplots(2, 3)
plot_nums = np.linspace(0, steps, num=6, dtype=int)
for i, num in enumerate(plot_nums):
    if i < 3:
        a_xy[0, i].scatter(xt[num, :, 0], xt[num, :, 1], s=10)
    else:
        a_xy[1, i - 3].scatter(xt[num, :, 0], xt[num, :, 1], s=10)
```

Comment: `gpe -= ... / np.sqrt(dist_sq)`, _ect_, are you sure that `dist_sq` is not close to zero?

Comment: That's in the force_point function which finds the force and gpe at a point in space due to a set of objects, and yes `dist` can tend to 0 but this can be dealt with by having `soft=True`. I did realise I missed the softening in force_calculator which is added, but doesn't change the outcome of running the code (also edited the post for some clarity too).

Comment: "Also, the kinetic energy seems orders of magnitude too large but I can't see where the issue with my calculation is." So, it produces the wrong answer? If that's so, the code isn't ready for review yet. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I didn't know that, sorry - but I fixed the small error so it works now, so it's acceptable now I updated the code?

Comment: I think that's better; would probably be easy to change the text and the title to make it on-topic. I'd like to see the answers, since this is relevant to my field of study.